# MySQL - get date column from a table

Tags: mysql, date

I have a MySQL db with a MappingTable which consists of two columns. First column is a `date` column and another is ID - `Autoincrement` int column. I created this table for mapping dates and the ID's. When I query the date column with dates to retrieve the ID, no rows are getting selected. Any reason?

I tried

1. `date_format` in the SELECT query
2. `str_to_date` while checking in the WHERE clause
3. Compared like `current_date > "2016-07-12"` AND `current_date <= "2016-07-12"`

IfI compare `LIKE "2016-07-1%"` I'm getting matching rows but if I select `"2016-07-12%"` though there are matching rows, it is giving 0 rows.

I defined my column as `DATE` only.

Anything I'm missing here?

```
CREATE TABLE `mapping_table` (
   `Current_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=26 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

My question is, I want to select something like this.

`select id from mapping_table where current_date="2016-07-12";`

I tried with all approaches as mentioned above, but no rows are not retrieving.

Comment: what's your question .?. is not clear .. please tell what's  you are looking for

Comment: Try using `current_date` BETWEEN DATE('2016-07-12')

Comment: @naviciroel: `BETWEEN` requires two dates to select set of dates.

Comment: @scaisEdge: I edited my question

Comment: @JAR now its more understandable..  have you tried current_date = date( '2016-07-12')?

Comment: Yup. I already tried that. But no luck!

Comment: @JAR I tried your select statement and its executing fine. It shows rows. try adding back tick on current_date = `current_date` cause its a keyword just in case.

Comment: +1 @naviciroel : Weird. it worked after putting back tick. Oh god! Thanks for the help. It's the date column and it's mandate to put back tick? I was not using this in Oracle SQL.

Comment: @JAR use back tick on columns and table names so it wont be read/parse as keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use back tick on columns and table names so it wont be read/parse as keyword.

```
 select `id` from `mapping_table` where `current_date` = "2016-07-12";
```

Answer (score 0):

In the sample you provided you should use  a date_format

```
select id from mapping_table where current_date= DATE_FORMAT("2016-07-12",'%Y-%d-%m') ;
```

or use a range

```
select id from mapping_table where current_date 
          BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT("2016-07-12",'%Y-%d-%m')  
              and DATE_FORMAT("2016-07-10",'%Y-%d-%m')
```